# Does anyone know of a place on the web I can find Kabbalat Shabbat sung from the people in a synagogue (preferably Ashkenazi)?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, synagogue, tehilim-psalms, song-poetry

[Here](https://youtu.be/B_vM8iiFJOY) is a perfect example of authentic singing, this is what I'm looking for but for Kabbalat Shabbat.

The problem for me is when people solo Tehillim they make their own version and that is not what I want to hear. It's very hard to record this because it's not shabbasdic, even though it might be halachicly ok to record it. For example the song for "Kol Adonei Al Hamaim" would be nice. I'm looking for the "full version" of Kabalat Shabbat - fully sung - (the songs which are usually sung at least) Thanks!

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XlJuY21J-WQ) is the closest I found but it's for the most famous song so no surprise there. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Uigo_ZA2oA&list=PL480D0414262B23BA) is something from Carlebach which resembles the regular way but for me, it's ruined when he solos, so this is not what I'm looking for but at least the names of the songs are.

Comment: "Kabalat Shabbat fully sang the way it is in most Synagoges”: I've no idea what this means. No synagogue I've been in sang it fully (meaning all of it). Even if some synagogues do so, probably not all such use the same tunes as one another. So how do you expect anyone to know what tunes you refer to?

Comment: In Sepharadic and Yemenite communities the entire Kabbalat Shabbat is sung or chanted out loud. But I get the feeling the OP isn't asking about such communities. I'm voting for this question to be closed.

Comment: I'll edit the question - I meant the whole service recorded, the songs which are sung - a lot of times are very famous and are sung in many communities in similar ways - also I don't mind the Sephardi or Yemenite way that'll also be interesting. I'm just looking for something more authentic than someone with a guitar doing a solo.

Comment: Do you know this site? http://www.zemirotdatabase.org/

Comment: I was taught to start at "L'hu l'rarnana" in the "Adonai Malach" mode (major key, like Psukei D'zimra on Shabbat) and change to a minor key at "Mizmor l'David".  Example: https://musescore.com/user/1030941/scores/480566

Comment: @MikeSupportsMonica thanks for the link but I'm looking for a video or recording where people actually sing it, I'm not very musical and the melody doesn't help me much...